# Why aren't Model and View Matrices separated in OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, matrix

With the programmable pipeline I can easily calculate the result with model and view separate, and it would simplify working with camera objects in the engine I'm making. I however wondered why they're not separate in the first place.
I read in another stackoverflow question that less matrices means less multiplying, but they're being multiplied in the first place as soon as I call GL.Translate() so that doesn't seem to hold up.
Before I end up spending time into working this out then notice days later that it causes problems and I have to rewrite half my code, why aren't they separated in the fixed function pipeline?

Comment: The simple reason is that separating them does not make sense. As you apply transform after transform, the respective matrix is multiplied with the one that the GL already knows. Later, when transforming vertices, they're multiplied with that single matrix each. You will not do anything different in the programmable pipeline, if performance means anything to you. There is nothing more complicated in this approach, only fewer computations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They essentially do take the same place in the pipeline so it makes sense to combine them early. Seldom would you wan't to perform a computation without them combined. A performance benefit is that the matrices can be multiplied together once per draw call, instead of per vertex in the vertex shader. Finally, the last advantage is that there is less bandwidth + uniforms when submitting draw calls.

If you really need to separate the two you can do that within your own shaders.

Comment: Didn't realize for some reason that multiplying in the shader would do it for every vertex

Answer (score 2):

Your question highlights one of the exact reasons OpenGL (and Direct3D) switched to a programmable pipeline. The answer always depends on what you are trying to achieve. Heck, in really simple programs, you can combine the projection, model, and view matrices. In fairly sophisticated engines, you want as many separate matrices as possible for lighting and whatnot.

So, the real answer is that it does not matter anymore. Use as many matrices as you need.

Answer (score 1):

That sounds about right... having the two matrices combined into one in the fixed-function pipeline has historically meant OpenGL has one less coordinate space to translate through on its way to drawing fragments. Matrix multiplication and storage are pretty cheap these days, but IrisGL and OpenGL date back to the 80s/90s.

You definitely are not going to run into any trouble using separate model and view matrices in the programmable pipeline. You're free to throw a lot of convention out the window with the programmable pipeline; linear Z-buffer, inverted depth range, etc...

You won't break anything like clipping, since that occurs using the *output* of the vertex shader, which should already be in clip space even if you got there by multiplying three matrices instead of two.